# Issue with conditional formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

```
=AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()-1))=1, TRUE)
```

When I use this in an excel formula, it correctly evaluates to true or false, depending on the previous column value.

But when I try to use it as part of the formula of conditional formatting, it always returns false and unable to set my conditional formatting based on the value.

The same conditional formatting works with excel 2003

Comment: Can you please put a screenshot of your data.

Comment: I don't get what the 2nd criteria "True" is doing. If you are just checking if the target cell is equal to 1 or not all you need is `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()-1))=1`

Comment: =AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()-1))=1, TRUE) >> Actually the TRUE is another condition and for brevity i avoided posting it. Additionally i debugged this complete formula and it returned true. I am thinking something to do with address function when used in conditional formatting context

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to try this

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()-1))=1
```

instead of

```
=AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()-1))=1, TRUE)
```

Comment: =AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()-1))=1, TRUE) >> Actually the TRUE is another condition and for brevity i avoided posting it. Additionally i debugged this complete formula and it returned true. I am thinking something to do with address function when used in conditional formatting context.

Comment: If it's not solved yet could you please post the screenshot of what exactly you are upto.